# Adding jQuery plugins to my rails 4 apps

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

It seems to be that I'm missing something, I am not being able to add `jQuery` plugins, lets say Mask plugin, I get errors trying to `$('form').mask()` with error `c.off` is not a function, 
I am willing to bet I am not being able to install the `js` files in the right place, I am using rails 4, what am I missing ?

also when I include them remotely in the

```
# application.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag  https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mask/1.13.9/jquery.mask.min.js" %>
```

I still get errors, not only with that specific plugin.

UPDATE:
I installed jquery.mask.min.js to vendor/assets/javascripts

[image]

I //= require jquery.mask.min.js in application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.mask.min.js
```

I try to $('input').mask('99-999-99');

I get error saying mask is not a function

[image]

Comment: Hey Kamal, could you please show us the error log; or screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, my bad, The problem was because of both requirng including jquery

once //= require at the application.js

and once <%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" %>

from the application layout.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the js file for the plugin and add it to your vendor/assets/javascript folder.  You then must require it in your app/assets/javascript/application.js file as:

```
//= require filename
```

If you put it in a subfolder for example named "jquery_plugins" in your vendors/assets/javascript folder you will need to require it in your assets/javascript/application.js file as follows:

```
//=require subfoldername/filename
```

Note: Make sure to leave off the js extension AND REQUIRE IT AFTER THE REQUIRE Jquery and Jquery-ui statements.  If it is a minified file you must add the .min to the require statement in your application.js file but not the '.js' extension. Ex:

```
//=require subfoldername/filename.min
```

Once done, restart your server and check again.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've specified jquery and rails, how about the jquery-rails gem:

https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails

which comes with any rails-jquery integration you might need built in. 
It requires a `bundle install` and the following two lines to be added to application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like you're trying to do, is add the -tag to your page. In which case what you'd want to do, is add

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mask/1.13.9/jquery.mask.min.js" %>
```

to your layout file, and not in your application.js-file.
Another way is to download the file, and include it in your application.js, by the `//=require .....`-method.

Comment: The first try I made was using this, still have mask is not a function.

Comment: You'll need jQuery included before this, but your functions using mask, afterwards. It has to be defined beforehand. Maybe not use a cdn, but downlaod the file to your project, and include it right after jquery in your application.js.erb